# Egg timer in Bash

Tags: performance, beginner, bash, timer

I just started to learn programming, going through a lot of different tutorials, trying out different programming languages and I stumble in the same sort of questions all over the place.

I give you an simple egg timer in bash I use for cooking.

```
#!/bin/bash

### varibales
min=$1
sec=$2
message=$3

### run
timer=$(($min * 60 + $sec))
for i in $(seq 0 $timer)
do 
remain=$(( $timer - $i ))
echo -ne "  $(($remain / 60)):$(($remain % 60))  \r"
sleep 1
done

echo -ne "                                  \r"
echo "$message"
afplay ~/alarm.mp3
```

This egg timer is very simple and therefore usually reliable. I use it for cooking. Yet, when I imagine doing it on a grander scale, there would be so many questions, that are neglectable in such a small application. But I am not sure if they would stay neglectable.

1. Is it a good idea to keep the additional variable `timer` in there? It helps readability, but wouldn't that hold another variable in my RAM? Shouldn't I better forget about readability and directly calculate it in the `echo` command. Same goes with the variables set for `min`, `sec` and `message`. Those variables are basically doubled for readability alone. I could directly use them in the script.
2. Using `sleep` to count down time. As far as I know, things like `sleep`, `wait` and `pause` can be off when the CPU is under heavy usage. Something probably to consider for scripts on my old raspberry, that only has one core. Shouldn't I first calculate the time of the alarm and then use my system time to calculate the time left? Should it do that in every iteration of the loop, that has to comes at least every second or should I only do it every minute or hour?
3. If I check it with system time, should I rather put the checks in interlapping loops than add an if check? Feels like an interlapping loop would take less processing power than use if checks every time it runs.
4. While we're on the question of waiting. How do I find good timings for programs? I mean, let's assume my program needs to check something regularily. Like, a file on the computer. How do I find a good timing for it? Every .5 second would feel pretty responsive. Yet, am I clogging my CPU with unnecessary checks? Is there some rule of thumb, like check 10 times more often for things on your RAM instead of things on your HD?

Like I said, those programs won't very much suffer from such things, but I wonder right now if I build on a wrong premise when trying to learn to code without considering writing effective code and are there any materials that you can point me to that answers these sorts of questions and hopefully a lot more questions I haven't thought of yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Your main questions

> Is it a good idea to keep the additional variable "timer" in there? It helps readability, but wouldn't that hold another variable in my RAM? Shouldn't I better forget about readability and directly calculate it in the "echo" command. Same goes with the variables set for "min", "sec" and "message". Those variables are basically doubled for readability alone. I could directly use them in the script.

Readability is extremely important. Write programs for people, not for computers. The computer has no problem reading a program that's written ugly. But it's not the computer that might have to search for bugs or implement the next feature, that's going to be a human. Code is read far more than it's written.

As far as RAM goes, the cost of an additional variable is negligible,
you can safely ignore it.

> Using "sleep" to count down time. As far as I know, things like "sleep", "wait" and "pause" can be off when the CPU is under heavy usage. Something probably to consider for scripts on my old raspberry, that only has one core. Shouldn't I first calculate the time of the alarm and then use my system time to calculate the time left? Should it do that in every iteration of the loop, that has to comes at least every second or should I only do it every minute or hour?

Yes, it will be more accurate to calculate the target end time, and in every iteration recalculate the remaining time to display. It's up to you how you pace the loop. Every second seems fine, with a `sleep 1` like it is now.

> If I check it with system time, should I rather put the checks in interlapping loops than add an if check? Feels like an interlapping loop would take less processing power than use if checks every time it runs.

I don't really get what an "interlapping" loop is, but in any case, you only need one loop, something like this: (see at the bottom a complete implementation)

```
target_time=...

while :; do
    current_time=$(date +%s)
    ((current_time >= target_time)) && break
    print_remaining_time current_time target_time
done
```

> While we're on the question of waiting. How do I find good timings for programs? I mean, let's assume my program needs to check something regularily. Like, a file on the computer. How do I find a good timing for it? Every .5 second would feel pretty responsive. Yet, am I clogging my CPU with unnecessary checks? Is there some rule of thumb, like check 10 times more often for things on your RAM instead of things on your HD?

That's a bit too broad to answer. It can depend on your hardware and specific circumstances and requirements. And looping is not always the right thing to do. In the example you gave, waiting for a file, it's better to look for a way to listen on filesystem events, rather than a loop with a sleep.

#### Code review

Bash arithmetics can help you simplify a lot. For example, instead of this:

> ```
> timer=$(($min * 60 + $sec))
> ```

You can write like this:

```
((timer = min * 60 + sec))
```

That is, you can drop all the `$` and use comfortable spacing around operators.

---

You did not indent the body of your `for` loop.
This is not easy to read. It would be better this way:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $timer)
do 
    remain=$(( $timer - $i ))
    echo -ne "  $(($remain / 60)):$(($remain % 60))  \r"
    sleep 1
done
```

---

`seq` is not standard, and therefore not recommended.
And you can easily achieve the same thing using `for`:

```
for ((i = 0; i < timer; ++i)); do
```

---

You did not validate your input.
If the script is called without parameters, the behavior will be odd.
It would be more friendly to display a help message to tell the user that something's wrong.

#### Suggested implementation

Applying some of the above suggestions (also borrowing a bit from the answer of [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success), a cleaner, safer, more readable implementation:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test $# -lt 3; then
    echo usage: $0 minutes seconds message
    exit 1
fi

min=$1
sec=$2
message=$3

((target_time = $(date +%s) + min * 60 + sec))
while :; do
    ((current_time = $(date +%s)))
    ((current_time >= target_time)) && break
    ((remain_sec_total = target_time - current_time))
    ((remain_min = remain_sec_total / 60))
    ((remain_sec = remain_sec_total % 60))
    printf '%4d:%02d  \r' $remain_min $remain_sec
    sleep 1
done

printf '%-7s\n' "$message"
```

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, this is a pretty good program for a beginner.  Using a carriage return so that the same line gets overwritten repeatedly is smart.  The program generally works well — not without concerns, but well enough.

To answer your questions directly:

1. The `$timer` variable is optional.  You could do without it, since your main objective is to count *down*, so `$remain` is more important.  But defining `$timer` is not an altogether bad idea.
2. Strictly speaking, yes, the use of `sleep` is somewhat problematic, but my main concern is not efficiency.  If you were truly concerned about efficiency, you wouldn't be using shell scripting at all, since invoking external commands is so much less efficient than calling functions within a typical programming language.

   Rather, I'm more concerned with accuracy.  `sleep N` guarantees that the process will be stopped for *at least N* seconds.  Given enough time, the clock could drift.  But fixing that problem is rather complicated, so I would just leave it.
3. I'm not sure what you mean by "overlapping loops".
4. Checking every second is fine.  Checking every half-second is still within the right ballpark.  Checking every two seconds is obviously too infrequent.

   The problem is, the `sleep` command doesn't necessarily handle intervals shorter than one second.  For example, from the [OS X `sleep(1)` man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sleep.1.html):

   > The `sleep` command will accept and honor a non-integer number of specified seconds (with a `.` character
   >    as a decimal point).  **This is a non-portable extension, and its use will nearly guarantee that a shell
   >    script will not execute properly on another system.**

   Therefore, I think that a smart design decision would be to keep it simple, and just sleep for one second at a time.  If the result is off by 5 seconds out of 5 minutes, the egg will still be OK.

The advice above applies to shell scripting.  If I were implementing this in C, I would make a different set of design trade-offs — perhaps aiming more for accuracy than simplicity.

---

Considering the remarks above, I'd just make minor changes to the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

min="$1"
sec="$2"
message="$3"

for remain in $(seq $((60 * $min + $sec)) 0); do
    printf '%4d:%02d\r' $(($remain / 60)) $(($remain % 60))
    sleep 1
done

# Ensure that the message is space-padded to at least 7 characters so as to
# overwrite the "0:00".
printf '%-7s\n' "$message"
```

Notably:

- Your `for` loop was not well formatted.
- Use `seq` to count down rather than up.
- Use `printf(1)` instead of `echo` so as to get the seconds to be zero-padded as necessary.

  A secondary consideration is that there are many implementations of `echo` (e.g. the [Bash built-in `echo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-echo) interprets its options differently from [GNU `/bin/echo`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html#echo-invocation), which may be different from [Solaris `/usr/bin/echo`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7m84/index.html)), whereas `printf` is better standardized.
- One smart use of `printf` can take care of both invocations of `echo` at the end (one of which is for clearing the line, and the other for actually printing the message).

Overall, I'd say that this is a fine program, and, given the inherent limitations of Bash, the design decisions you have made are reasonable.  You're on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding #2: You can also count the time in advance and then just check whether the current time is still less than the final time.

```
#!/bin/bash
start_time=$(date +%s)
min=$1
sec=$2
message=$3
end_time=$((start_time + sec + 60 * min))

until (( current_time >= end_time )) ; do
    sleep 1
    current_time=$(date +%s)
    echo -ne $(( end_time - current_time )) seconds remaining... $'\r'
done
echo $'\n'"$message"
```

You can also have a look at [at](http://linux.die.net/man/1/at).